# What triggers "active today" with no apparent activity?

Tags: discussion

A question asked in 2011 popped up [Dynamic URLs and links to many affiliate links from one PHP page](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8065/dynamic-urls-and-links-to-many-affiliate-links-from-one-php-page) as `active today`.

There is nothing obvious that has changed (edit, comment), so what is it that bumps a very old question to the top by flagging it as `active today`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There was a answer made six hours before you posted this question. That answer was deleted as it was a new user asking a new question. But deleted answers require 10,000 rep to see so to most users it looks like nothing changed.

Comment: Thanks John.  Perhaps it might be worth passing to those who make such decisions that if the nett result of activity is no change, then the "active today" flag be reversed.  It is misleading.

Comment: It isn't true for this case, but another reason that posts can get onto the home page without activity: Questions that have an answer with no votes can also be "bumped" by the community user to get more attention.   There used to be a message when that happened, but Stack Exchange recently took that away.  You can however see community bumps in the question timeline.

Comment: I raised this concern on the Stack Exchange meta site: [Indicate publicly why questions with deleted answers are bumped](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/354677/indicate-publicly-why-questions-with-deleted-answers-are-bumped)